# why mysql client can connect to SSL-enabled mysql5.6 through private IP without using --ssl-ca operation,but can't through Public Ip?

Tags: mysql, ssl, tls1.2

In my IDC DATACENTER ， i deploy a SSL-enabled mysql5.6 whih Self-signed CA and server Certificate。And my user have 'require ssl' operation.

==================================================================================================

MySQL root@[(none)]>select user,host,ssl_type from mysql.user where user='ssl_test2';

| user      | host | ssl_type |

| ssl_test2 | %    | ANY      |

MySQL root@[(none)]>show variables like '%ssl%';

| Variable_name | Value                |

| have_openssl  | YES                  |

| have_ssl      | YES                  |

| ssl_ca        | /tmp/ca.pem          |

| ssl_cert      | /tmp/server-cert.pem |

| ssl_key       | /tmp/server-key.pem  |

==================================================================================================

I can connect to this mysql from another IDC machine ,command:"mysql -u ssl_test2 -p -h [private IP] -P 3306" . Some sensitive information will be hiddened.

==================================================================================================

[mysql@GP-APS-SET02 ~]$ mysql xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 221
Server version: 5.6.45-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

### MySQL risk-yun@[(none)]>\s

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19, for linux-glibc2.12 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

## Connection id:          221
Current database:
Current user:           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
SSL:                    Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA

But i have a application server on the cloud,so i need to connect to the mysql  through pulic IP.The command like this" mysql -u ssl_test2 -p -h [public IP] -P [PORT] "
I will get the error "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user xxxxxx (using password: YES)"

If i provide the ca Certificate on cloud ECS， command like "mysql --ssl-ca=ca.pem"， i can connect to mysql sucessfully and ssl encrypt sucessfully too.

So how can i connect to mysql without ssl-sa operation through public ip? And why ?

Comment: Please improve formatting. Your question is not easy to read/scan.

Answer (score 0):

alter user ssl_test2@'%' require none;
flush privileges;
select host,user from mysql.user

then:
check your ECS security group firewalld

Comment: "require none" operation is not is not what I want 。